# grails - How to parse POI numeric value in a column

Tags: grails, apache-poi

I am using POI to import my books in an Excel file to my domain class.  It turns out that Excel marks the columns in a row either as String or Numeric, or Formula, etc.

I have a column that has mix contents with number and string.  The contents are actually the ID of the books.  All the contents should be treated as String.

This is an example:

```
Column 1
1234567
8910.0
One2Three
456
```

Excel marks Row 1, 2 and 4 as Numeric.  I use the getCell() method to read the content of the cell.

```
String bookId = row.getCell(1).toString().trim() // row is a HSSFRow
```

POI returns "1234567.0", "8910.0", "One2Three", and "456.0".

How do I get rid of the ".0" substring correctly?

```
"1234567.0" in row 1 should be just "1234567"
"8910.0" in row 2 should be as-is "8910.0"
"One2Three" in row 3 is just "One2Three"
"456.0" in row 4 should be just "456"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to spot what you're doing wrong...

Comment: I use the HSSFRow.getCell(1).toString().trim() method to read the content of the cell.

Comment: Try with `DataFormatter` ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code it's hard to know exactly what your problem is, but this is how we do it, to extract an integer value from cell 9 in the row:

```
row.cells[9].cell.numericCellValue as Integer
```

Comment: This is not working correctly.  This will mess up "8910.0" in row 2, and it will get an exception in row 3 where the content is not a number.

Comment: We tried and looked in the API in POI for a "magic" way to convert the contents of a Cell to the right data type. The fact is, that this is not possible, and even if you have steely requirements for your users not to mess with cell types, sometimes, you will want to have "3" as a String, because that's what it supposed to be, and sometimes you will want the number. It's impossible for POI to guess what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to make POI to import my book Id correctly now.  I set the cell to String before I call the getCell() method.  POI gives me the correct content from getCell().toString() method now.  I haven't tried a cell with a Link or Formula data type.  I am pretty sure this won't work with these other data type in the cell.

```
row.getCell(1).setCellTypeImpl(CellType.STRING)
bookId = row.getCell(1).toString().trim()
```

After I set the cell to the STRING cell type, POI returns all the mixed content in column 1 as-is.

Good job me!

Comment: exactly my point in the answer. You had to let Groovy decide how to do the conversion to String, in this case, groovy did what you would expect, but there is no silver bullet. This is why, in my response I explicitly us as Integer. At some point YOU need to set the expectations of what the cell is supposed to contain.